# Setting content inside of a UITableViewCell from outside source?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with a few UITableViewCells. Each of those cells have different content: labels, images, text fields, etc. I am needing to set those pieces of content based around user interaction of my UITableViewController class.

For example: I have a cell that has a UIImageView in it. When a user taps the UIImageView I want a UIActionSheet to show. The problem is that I can't set the UIImageView as a property of the UITableViewController class. It has to be a property of a subclass for that UITableViewCell. But that means if I write the code for showing a UIActionSheet in the UITableViewCell subclass it won't show in the UITableViewController class.

My question is, since all of the objects within a UITableViewCell are in their own class, how do I alert the UITableViewController class when one of those actions happens?

Also, when a UIActionSheet is displayed it will need to show up in my UITableViewController class. If I select an item from that action sheet and wanted the text of that item to propagate to setting the text of a UILabel inside of a UITableViewCell, how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `UITableViewController` you control everything through the `UITableViewDataSource` implementation.

Here is how you can do it: make an `int` field in your model class that says which row needs to show a cell with an action sheet, and set it to `-1` (which means that no cell needs to show an action sheet). In the tap handler of the `UIImageView` call the model, and tell it that the cell to which the `UIImageView` belongs needs an action sheet now. At that point you tell your `UITableView` to reload data. This sets the whole system in motion again - the table view calls back your data source to ask for the count, and then it calls again for the cell. This is when your data source looks at the model, sees that the row needs an action sheet, and returns a subclass of the cell with the action sheet visible.

Here is a diagram showing this sequence of events.

[image: Interaction diagram]

When the user is done with the action sheet, the action sheet needs to call the model again, and tell it that the action sheet is no longer needed (i.e. set the index back to `-1`). After that it should call the table view again, and tell it to reload the data. The sequence will repeat again, but is time there will be no flag asking for the action sheet, so a regular cell would be returned.

Comment: Very elegant way of doing this! Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

well, I simply suggest to use Custom UITableView Cell class, so when you are creating custom cell pass your uitableview controller to that class as parent. Now in your Custom Class you can add singleTap on UIImageView, from tap on it you can call method in your parent class via parent object you have already passed.